# Polygon is not drawing // saying the variable doesn't exist, but there are no errors returning in console

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to make a polygon show up on the map, the data I'm using on this map is from a database with an array when I `console.log` this `[obj[2][0].geometry.coordinates[0][0][0]` I get these coordinates `4.87896` and the full coordinates I'm trying to use are these

```
0: (2) ["4.87896", "52.367477"]
1: (2) ["4.87896", "52.379843"]
2: (2) ["4.918785", "52.379843"]
3: (2) ["4.918785", "52.367477"]
4: (2) ["4.87896", "52.367477"]
```

and the code how I'm trying to make the polygon get shown on the map

```
let map = L.map('map').setView([52.37, 4.90], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 14,

}).addTo(map);
var polygon = L.polygon([
        [obj[2][0].geometry.coordinates[0][0][0], obj[2][0].geometry.coordinates[0][0][1]],
        [obj[2][0].geometry.coordinates[0][1][0], obj[2][0].geometry.coordinates[0][1][1]],
        [obj[2][0].geometry.coordinates[0][2][0], obj[2][0].geometry.coordinates[0][2][1]],
        [obj[2][0].geometry.coordinates[0][3][0], obj[2][0].geometry.coordinates[0][3][1]],
        [obj[2][0].geometry.coordinates[0][4][0], obj[2][0].geometry.coordinates[0][4][1]]
    ]).addTo(map);
```

The polygon is not showing on the map but there are no errors returning in the `console`also when I type `polygon` in `console`it can not find it.

> VM94:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: polygon is not defined
>       at :1:1

all the links I use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
      crossorigin=""/>
<!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
```

Edit:
a bin to the js

https://output.jsbin.com/lewaroc/1

Comment: This looks odd. Can you make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of this, in jsfiddle or jsbin or [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) or whatever?

Comment: made an js bin @IvanSanchez

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I found out that the coord only accept `numbers` so in this case it had to be `Number([obj[2][0].geometry.coordinates[0][0][0])` and then it draws fine